# Checkbox in some cells but not all, in a particular column - JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

This may be a vague query, so please pardon me.

Customized JTable (I've modified the query and will discuss based on the SSCCE provided). I've to create a JTable to provide authorization based on selected checkboxes in JTable

Purpose of this JTable is to show users with all of the menu options of the application. This JTable have three columns:
First column: class Bollean (checkbox)
Second column: class String (main menu items)
Third column: class String (sub-menu items)

To provide authorization user shall select checkbox corresponding to sub-menu items and finally select "Authorize" button (I haven't included authorize button in this as my authorize functionality is working fine)

Now the UI requirement is that in the first column of JTable, I should display checkboxes corresponding to sub-menu items only instead of displaying checkbox in each cell of first column (in other words it should not display checkbox corresponding to main menu menu item)

Pic below is expected output (although I'm getting all cells in first column with checkbox)

[image: Expected UI]

```
public class SwingSolution extends JPanel {

    public SwingSolution() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        String[] columnNames = {"", "Main Menu", "Sub Menu"};

        Object[][] data = {
        {false, "File", ""},
        {false, "", "New"},
        {false, "", "Save"},
        {false, "", "Close"},
        {false, "Edit", ""},
        {false, "", "Delete"},
        {false, "", "Format"},
        {false, "Project", ""},
        {false, "", "Create New"},
        {false, "", "Delete"},
        {false, "", "Build"},
        {false, "", "Properties"},
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        final JTable table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        return Boolean.class;
                    case 1:
                        return String.class;
                    case 2:
                        return String.class;
                    default:
                        return Boolean.class;
                }
            }
        };

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(30);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(100);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(120);

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(250, 195));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SwingSolution newContentPane = new SwingSolution();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried various things with cell renderer and googled about JTable and custom cells but couldn't figured it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: There is an extra comma in your array declaration (though it may be not the case )

Comment: Thanks for noticing.. edited now (although it wouldn't have given any error or change in behavior of the program)

Comment: I have a suggestion: can you just create a static table (it's very simple, indeed) and then access its elements via jQuery, as it's done, for example, in my online quiz engine (link to demo: http://webinfocentral.com/)? The details of implementation are in my article: Click/select Row in ASP.NET GridView or HTML Table (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/209416/Make-the-entire-GridView-Row-clickable-and-selecta)

Comment: Then I've to read about jQuery, which would be nice for my knowledge but maybe not so nice for this tight deadline. I already made a prototype with JTree (with checkboxes).. MadProgrammer has suggested a solution, working on it.. and should be able to present both (JTable and JTree) of these prototypes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you're going to have supply you're cell renderer and editor.

In this case, I changed the first columns value/type to `int`.  This allows me to supply additional meaning beyond `boolean`.

If the column value is `0` then the cell is not "selectable", `1` is unchecked, `2` is checked.

I also altered the `isCellEditable` method of the `TableModel` to only allow the "active" cells to be editable.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class LimitedTableCellEditor extends JPanel {

    public LimitedTableCellEditor() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        String[] columnNames = {"", "Main Menu", "Sub Menu",};

        Object[][] data = {
            {0, "File", ""},
            {1, "", "New"},
            {1, "", "Save"},
            {1, "", "Close"},
            {0, "Edit", ""},
            {1, "", "Delete"},
            {1, "", "Format"},
            {0, "Project", ""},
            {1, "", "Create New"},
            {1, "", "Delete"},
            {1, "", "Build"},
            {1, "", "Properties"},};

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        final JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        return Integer.class;
                    case 1:
                        return String.class;
                    case 2:
                        return String.class;
                    default:
                        return Boolean.class;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                boolean editable = false;
                if (column == 0) {
                    Object value = getValueAt(row, column);
                    if (value instanceof Integer) {
                        editable = ((int)value) != 0;
                    }
                }
                return editable;
            }
        };

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(30);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new ConditionalCheckBoxRenderer());
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(100);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(120);

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(250, 195));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        LimitedTableCellEditor newContentPane = new LimitedTableCellEditor();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class ConditionalCheckBoxRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {

        private static final Border NO_FOCUS_BORDER = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);
        private JCheckBox cb;

        public ConditionalCheckBoxRenderer() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setOpaque(false);
            cb = new JCheckBox();
            cb.setOpaque(false);
            cb.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            cb.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            add(cb);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setOpaque(isSelected);
            if (isSelected) {
                setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                setForeground(table.getForeground());
            }
            if (value instanceof Integer) {
                int state = (int) value;
                cb.setVisible(state != 0);
                cb.setSelected(state == 2);
            }
            if (hasFocus) {
                setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
            } else {
                setBorder(NO_FOCUS_BORDER);
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've not done the editor, but the basic concept is the same...

Comment: UI display is perfect although UI behavior is bit strange: Firstly, Single selection of checkbox is not working, I need to double click. And Secondly checkbox displays int value instead of selection

Comment: @Mandy This is actually the default behavior for the cell editors.  You need to create you own (as the table will be using it's `int` cell editor) and override the `isCellEdtiable` method to return true ;)

Comment: Alright.. was thinking the same.. let me try my hands on the code and get back to you if I face any other problem regarding the same

Comment: I deliberately didn't include the editor, you're going to have to provide your own implementation (similar to the renderer), except you won't need to worry about the `0` state, as the table model won't allow those cells to be editable ;)

Comment: For a moment in excitement I forgot this isn't a magic site for solutions but better than that, as getting ideas and assistance in order to get better understanding and ultimately improvising

Comment: Something seems odd to me. If the value is actually "true" before being rendered, then I see no check in the box. I assume this was "intentional" with reference to the create-your-own-editor, but the example seems a bit misleading. I think it is assuming the starting value is "false"?

Comment: @jahn Based on the code, none of the items in the model are actually selected, the code assumes a tri-state, visible, not selected, selected

Answer (score 2):

Override the `getCellRenderer()` method to return an appropriate renderer. Something like:

```
@Override
public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column)
{
    int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToView(column);

    if (modelColumn == 0 && getValueAt(row, column).equals(""))
        return getDefaultRenderer(String.class);
    else
        return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
}
```

You would also need to change the data in the model:

```
{"", "File", ""},
```

Finally you would also override the `isCellEditable()` method to make the empty cell non editable.

Then you can just use the default Boolean renderer/editor for the other rows in the column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Boolean` wrapper class instead of the raw type and write your own `TableCellRenderer` and override the `getTableCellRendererComponent(..)` method.

```
public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    public CustomTableCellRenderer()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, 
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if(value instanceof Boolean)
        {
            if(value != null)
            {
                 JCheckBox jcb = new JCheckBox();
                 jcb.setSelected((Boolean) value);

                 return jcb;
            }
            return new JPanel();
        }
    return this;
    }
}
```

Then just simply set `infos.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, new CustomTableCellRenderer());` and replace your raw types in the array with `new Boolean(true)`. Wherever you don't want to have a `JCeckBox` you put a `null` instead of a `Boolean` and an empty `JPanel` will appear.

Comment: Thanks! But the best way is the combination of this with MadProgrammer's answer. (I had some problems with the placement of the CheckBox, so I added it to a JPanel which is initialized inside the overridden method)