# Make a JPane to refresh or repaint

Tags: java, swing

I try to make a program where I save my links and password or any short words that can help me , a make this code.

This is the main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Second ob = new Second();
   ob.setLocation(450,30);
   ob.setSize(600, 700);
    ob.setVisible(true);
    ob.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}}
```

and here is the second class

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
 import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Second extends JFrame {
    private int i;
    private int numberlink = 200;//numarul maxim de linkuri
    private int[] deleteTable = new int[numberlink];
    private JPanel pan1;
    private JButton[] buton = new JButton[numberlink];
    private Box box;
    private String namefile = "stocarenume.txt";
    private int numberbutton;
    private Scanner scaner;
    private String array_nume[] = new String[numberlink];
    private String array_url[] = new String[numberlink];
    private JButton butonadd;
    private ActionListener listener, listenerDelete;
    private String namefile_url = "stocare_url.txt";
    private BufferedWriter file_set;
    private JScrollPane scrollpane;
    private GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    private JButton del = new JButton("Delete");
    private JRadioButton[] deleteCeck = new JRadioButton[numberlink];
    private JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();
    private JButton delete = new JButton("Delete");

    Second() {

        box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        pan1 = new JPanel();
        pan1.setBackground(Color.gray);
        pan1.setLocation(0, 0);
        add(pan1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        butonadd = new JButton("Add");
        pan1.add(butonadd);
        pan1.add(delete);

        //am facut o variabil listener in care am suprascris pentru cele numberlink de butoane
        // in care am facut sa imi returneze linkul din array_url

        listener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
                    for (i = 0; i < numberlink; i++) {
                        if (array_nume[i] == e.getActionCommand()) {
                            String myString = array_url[i];
                            //iti pune in clipboard linkul ,ca si cum ai da copy la un test dar tu de fapt apesi doar pe un buton
                            StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
                            Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                            clpbrd.setContents(stringSelection, null);

                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        };

        delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getActionCommand() == "Delete") {
                    for (i = 0; i < numberlink; i++) {
                        if (deleteTable[i] == 1) {
                            array_url[i] = "xxxxxx";
                            array_nume[i] = "xxxxxx";

                        }
                    }
                    scriere_fisier();
                }
            }
        });

        listenerDelete = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Object c = (Object) e.getSource();

                for (i = 0; i < numberlink; i++) {
                    if (c == deleteCeck[i]) {
                        deleteTable[i] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        };



        butonadd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (e.getActionCommand() == "Add") {
                    numberbutton++;

                    String nume;
                    String url;

                    nume = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduceti numele ");
                    url = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduceti url ");
                    array_nume[numberbutton] = nume;
                    array_url[numberbutton] = url;
                    scriere_fisier();
                }


            }
        });

        citirefisier();
        creerebutoane();

    }


    void citirefisier() {
        try {

            scaner = new Scanner(new File(namefile));
            i = 0;
            while (scaner.hasNext()) {
                array_nume[i] = scaner.nextLine();

                i++;

            }
            numberbutton = i - 1;


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        try {

            scaner = new Scanner(new File(namefile_url));
            i = 0;
            while (scaner.hasNext()) {
                array_url[i] = scaner.nextLine();

                i++;

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }


    void creerebutoane() {


        pan2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;

        constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);

        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;


        for (i = 1; i <= numberbutton; i++) {
            buton[i] = new JButton(array_nume[i]);
            buton[i].addActionListener(listener);

            pan2.add(buton[i], constraints);

            constraints.gridy++;


        }
        constraints.gridx = 2;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 50, 0, 0);

        for (i = 1; i <= numberbutton; i++) {
            deleteCeck[i] = new JRadioButton();
            deleteCeck[i].addActionListener(listenerDelete);
            pan2.add(deleteCeck[i], constraints);
            constraints.gridy++;

        }

        scrollpane = new JScrollPane(pan2);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(500, 200);
        scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(d.height);
        d.height *= 10; // Show at least 10 buttons
        scrollpane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(d);
        add(scrollpane);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }




    void scriere_fisier() {

        try {

            file_set = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(namefile));

            for (i = 1; i <= numberbutton; i++) {
                file_set = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(namefile, true));

                if (array_nume[i].equals("xxxxxx")) {
                } else {
                    file_set.newLine();
                    file_set.write(array_nume[i]);
                }
                file_set.close();

            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nu sa putut scrie in " + namefile);
        }
        try {
            file_set = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(namefile_url));

            for (i = 1; i <= numberbutton; i++) {
                file_set = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(namefile_url, true));
                if (array_url[i].equals("xxxxxx")) {
                } else {
                    file_set.newLine();
                    file_set.write(array_url[i]);
                }
                file_set.close();

            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nu sa putut scrie in " + namefile_url);

        }

    }

}
```

And now I try to explain what I make , a make 2 file where save the url as the name.

Here is a image where look the app:

[image: screen capture of GUI]

And when a press add show me 2 InputDialog and a write name and what I want to save , and the problem is I add something or I delete something but I need to close and open again the program to see the change that I make, I try with repaint to refresh the pan2 , but nothing.

Comment: *"I try with repaint to refresh the pan2 , but nothing."* Where did you call `repaint()`? It's not in your code. Try calling `revalidate()` before `repaint()`

Comment: I think what you really want to do is have a look at a `JTable`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is all over the place, for example, you create a delete and add listener which do nothing and then add different listeners to the buttons, so I have no idea what's actually going on...

This...

```
if (e.getActionCommand() == "Add") {
```

is not how `String` comparison works in Java.  If you're making this simple mistake, then you might not be ready for something as complex as GUI programing

Based on what I've read, when you add or remove an item, you update the model, save it, but never actually add any components to the screen.

Having said all that, I would suggest a different approach and use either a `JList` or a `JTable`, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453197/checkbox-in-some-cells-but-not-all-in-a-particular-column-jtable/16453304#16453304)

Comment: ok I understand that I not  good ,but how I make the code if I press add buton e.getActionComand() return the name of the button and in this case the name is "Add" :

Comment: if I need someoane to say me that I not know java gui not write here

Comment: @cosminciuciu With respect, you've made a dozen or more rookie mistakes which are only complicated by the fact that you're trying to work with a complex API wrapped around a complex paradigm. Spending some time coming to terms with the basic use of the language and API is going to save you (and us) a lot of headaches and wasted time. If you don't want to do that, smile, say thanks and move one, don't be a AH about it.

Comment: @cosminciuciu As to your first comment, you've already added components to container once, I would then assume you have the know for all to do it again. A `JList` or `JTable` would be better long term solution, while more complex, they present a structure which is suited to what you are trying to do. I would highly recommend taking another look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details

Comment: @cosminciuciu Oh, I'm all for stretching yourself and trying to advance your skills, I certainly don't want to hold you back in that regard, in fact, I'd be among the first to help you, but you don't want to break yourself in the process, preparation is the key to success, spending a day or two building on some additional fundamentals, trying some ideas in isolation will help you overcome many of the hurdles you will face everyday in your development life

Answer (score 0):

I think you should revalidate first and then repaint after any change. Revalidate check if there is any change in the component. Also you can use a JButton when you click on it reload all content.

Like a suggestion is more reliable if you have more separated your code. All the logic in one or two classes is not good. A simple program does not mean that good programming practices have to be abandoned.